# makes solutions to others' problem inconvenience to her

Tags: meaning-in-context

Karen

Middle aged woman, typically blonde, ***makes*** solutions to others' problems an inconvenience to her although she isn't even remotely affected.

Karen sues the local city council after they installed a new STOP sign that hides the sun from her window for two minutes a day. The sign was installed after a school boy on his bicycle was hit by a speeding driver and died.

[Source](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3fterm=Karen&amp=true)

---

I'm having trouble in understanding "***makes***".
I'd like to know what "***makes***" means in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AHD "make"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=make)

The sense is any of these:

> 18. a. To draw a conclusion as to the significance or nature of: *don't know what to make of the decision.*
>     b. To calculate as being; estimate: *I make the height 20 feet.*
>     c. To consider as being: *wasn't the problem some people made it.*

So, in that  context, is means that the typical woman spoken of sees the solution of the problem of the intersection being dangerous as a personal inconvenience to her.

(Apart from that, that Urban Dictionary definition is a malign flaunting of stereotypes.)